# What's an easy way of sorting custom post types manually?

Tags: custom-post-types, sort

I'm using the bbpress plugin. It has a custom post type called **forums**. I used to sort posts by changing its publishing date. But you can't do that with this custom post type.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used this code to create custom post template for specific post type

```
define(SINGLE_PATH, TEMPLATEPATH.'/single');    
function product_single_page_template($product) {
        global $wp_query, $post;
        $type = get_post_type();
        if ($type==true) 
            if(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '-type-' . $type . '.php'))
            return SINGLE_PATH . '-type-' . $type . '.php';
        return $product;
}
add_filter('single_template', 'product_single_page_template');
```

you can do the same with categories or for non single pages just as well.